# Is this a legit claim for a patent for a media to grow bacteria?

Tags: patent-infringement, soy

Can a patent for the media used to grow a specific bacteria be as broad as this?  This patent claims all animal free media is covered by this patent, how can that be?  Is the claim here that no one can use soy in a media to grow C. tetani without a patent infringement (unless they add in at least 10% animal product) despite different media components and proportions?